# JQuery AJAX success не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

При клике отправляется объект на сервер, **статус == 200**, но `success` не срабатывает, вместо него работает `error`, что не так ?

Код:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$(".popup-form__btn").click(function() {

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "название сайта",
dataType: 'json',
data: "param="+JSON.stringify(burgObj),
success: function() {
$('<p>Ваша заявка принята !</p>').appendTo('.success');

},
error: function() {
    $('<p>Ошибка при передаче данных !</p>').appendTo('.success');
},
 });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: какойто странный у вас JSON.stringify, с конкатенацией строки в начале, хотя она тоже по идее должна быть внутри функции. И второе с сервера тоже должен прийти json а не что-то иное, типа echo или что там за ответ в вашем случае

Comment: Подскажите, как организовать ответ сервера в формате JSON и что должен ответить сервер ?

Comment: У вас не верный `json` и покажите как парсится он на сервере. А так же в консоле посмотрите что в ответе. Там скорее всего ошибка парсинга.

Comment: Все решил, проблема оказалась в том, что не было ответа от сервера.
С JSON всё было в порядке. На сервере 'json_decode($POST['param'])', а далее с ним можно работать, как с объектом в PHP.